# Removing isolated nodes in order to make the graph connected

Tags: networkx

I have a graph that is not connected.

```
import json
import networkx as nx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph

G = nx.read_gml('/Users/luca/Desktop/networks_analysis/astro-ph/astro-ph.gml')

print(nx.info(G))
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 16706
Number of edges: 121251
Average degree:  14.5159

nx.is_connected(G)
False
```

I tried to remove all isolated nodes but the graph still remain non-connected.

```
G.remove_nodes_from(list(nx.isolates(G)))

print(nx.info(G))
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 16046
Number of edges: 121251
Average degree:  15.1129

nx.is_connected(G)
False
```

How can I obtain a connected graph?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the largest connected subgraph with:

```
nodes = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
H = nx.subgraph(G, nodes)
```